# Split Java string with quotes into args with no quotes

Tags: java, split

I need to split my string into 3 *args* with each *arg* being what is within the quotes and store them in separate variables.

Here is what I have. The code below takes all command line arguments and combines them into one large `String`.

Example of a string I need to convert:

```
“METRO Blue Line” “Target Field Station Platform 1” “south”
```

It should become:

```
var1 = METRO Blue Line
var2 = Target Field Station Platform 1
var3 = south
```

I've tried a lot with `split("\"")` but for whatever reason it doesn't even remove the quotes for me.

```
// Construct a string to hold the whole args. 
// Implemented it this way because args is separated by spaces
String combine = "";
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
{
    combine = combine.concat(args[i]);
    combine = combine.concat(" ");
}
System.out.println(combine);
```

Comment: Does your `String` contain smart quotes?

Answer (score 1):

You are using curved quote (aka Smart Quotes) marks and not accounting it in code

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[“”]");
    String text = "“METRO Blue Line” “Target Field Station Platform 1” “south” ";
    String arr[] = text.split("\\”");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(pattern.matcher(arr[i]).replaceAll("").trim());
    }
```

Comment: The double `replaceAll` is unnecessary here and introduces an increased overhead (especially if OP wants to use that code on big datasets). The method accepts a **regex** and since your action is the same for both quotes you could simply use `replaceAll("[“”]", "")`. Also the escaping is not necessary, these are no special symbols to regex. But nonetheless useful answer, pretty compact especially.

Comment: Good point @Zabuza. also added another optimization to avoid re-compiling regex on each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols `”` and `“` are different to the symbol `"`. If you split with `split("\"")` you obviously search for `"` but not for the other quote symbols `”` and `“`.

You could easily extract them with a `Matcher` and its `find` method. Or alternatively use your splitting approach with the **correct delimiter**: `split("” “")`. Note that the first and last element will then have a single quote, just remove it.

---

```
String input = "“METRO Blue Line” “Target Field Station Platform 1” “south”";
String[] elements = input.split("” “");

// Remove first quote
elements[0] = elements[0].substring(1);
// Remove last quote
String lastElement = elements[elements.length - 1];
elements[elements.length - 1] = lastElement.substring(0, lastElement.length() - 1);

// Output all results
for (String element : elements) {
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

The output is:

```
METRO Blue Line
Target Field Station Platform 1
south
```

---

An advantage of this approach is that it is very efficient, no extra replacements or stuff like that, just one iteration over the input, nothing more.

Comment: this assumes the exact position of quotes. any extra white space at the beginning, end, or between quoted sections will cause it to fail.

Comment: That is correct and it is good that you mention it for OP. The problem may be easily avoided by using the `String#trim` method and easy split patterns like `split("”\\s*“")`. Else OP should probably provide more example inputs.

Comment: yeah, it depends on where the input is coming from. it might be expected to be strictly formatted. but if it's something like a command line argument, you would have to be more lenient in the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

In keeping with the RegEx theme of the original answer, I've rewritten my answer to find either normal quotes or smart quotes.

```
String text = "“METRO Blue Line” “Target Field Station Platform 1” “south”";

String regex = "\"([^\"]*)\"|“([^”]*)”";

ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();

Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(text);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        listOfStrings.add(m.group(1));
    } 
    if (m.group(2) != null) {
        listOfStrings.add(m.group(2));
    }
}
for (String temp : listOfStrings) {
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Note that the input of OP does not have `"` but rather `“` and `”` (smart quotes). These are different symbols and thus your code will not work with OPs specific input. However I like that you show a `Matcher#find` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.join() from java 8. Code example

```
String[] strArray = { "How", "To", "Do", "In", "Java" };
String joinedString = String.join(", ", strArray);System.out.println(joinedString);
```

Output:

How, To, Do, In, Java

Comment: I think the problem of OP is the other way around, he needs to split the complete string into pieces.